# Photoshop GIF color dithering problem

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

Trying to make a GIF in Photoshop CC here, but having some problems over the quality of the color in some images.

When I have 100% dithering, some dark pixels appear in a green area over this logo:

[image]

But when I reduce the dithering, even just to 99%, the dark pixels disappear:

The thing is, when I reduce the dithering to 99%, the quality of color in the other pictures I used gets compromised.

I guess what I'm asking is if there's a way to have 100% dithering without the dark pixels appearing in the logo.

Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 2):

Change the palette to "adaptive" and/or increase the number of colors. With a only 3 colors (including white) there is no reason to dither at all if you use adaptive with 256 color indices.

Comment: There are many more than 3 colors present due to the antialiasing, but your point is still well taken.  8 or 16 colors would probably be fine for this logo.

Comment: Yeah, 256 would allow for 128 levels of gradation between a color and white for each one Probably overkill.